# how to change systemd unit files directory?

Tags: centos, systemd

Since I want to put all my service unit files in my own directory like `/opt/myservice/`, I found the way that use `$SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` in question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224992/where-do-i-put-my-systemd-unit-file/367237#367237, however systemdctl can't find my service file in `/opt/myservice/` after I set`SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` with shell command `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/opt/myservice/`, anyone knows how can it work? thx

```
[root@localhost system]# ls /opt/myservice/
test.service
[root@localhost system]# export SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/opt/myservice/
[root@localhost system]# echo $SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH
/opt/myservice/
[root@localhost system]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@localhost system]# systemctl status test.service
Unit test.service could not be found.
```

Comment: Yes, I mean do not use absolute path for systemct.

Comment: Are you exporting `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH`?

Comment: Yes, I tried `export SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/opt/myservice/`, but didn't work.

Comment: `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` probably needs to be set on the systemd process, not on `systemctl`  – try running `systemctl set-environment SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/opt/myservice/`.

Comment: It dosen't work too, although SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH correct in `systemctl show-environment`

Answer (score 0):

From the document, the environment variable must be set as the kernel environement.

So, if the pid of systemd is 1, the environment must be set as kernel option, any others are invalid (e.g. /etc/profile, systemctl set-envionrment)

If you use grub-driven system, you can set it in `/etc/default/grub`, change the line starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` and append  `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/absolute/path/to/your/services:`. The last colon is required if you just want to append your services path.